# adjust the height of the "div's" according to the container

Tags: css

How can I do to make the "div-3" in the container are adjusted for the height that this has.

I need the fit the high "div-3" left by div's 1 and 2, no matter what the content of this div-3 incomplete.

It may be that the div 1 or div 2 are not display (display:none).

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<style>
.container{
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}
.container div{
}
.div-1{
    background-color:#009966;
}
.div-2{
    background-color:#999999;
}
.div-3{
    background-color:#3399FF;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div-1">g f erg erg erg rga f erg erg erg rga</div>
    <div class="div-2">
        sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sf erg erg erg rgadf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />sdf<br />
    </div>
    <div class="div-3">b gf erg erg erg rga</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? What do you mean with your last sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. But, if in your CSS, instead of using height, use min-height, if your div contents are less than the specified height, it'll still force the 300px, and if it's greater, it'll automatically adjust.

e.g.

```
.container{
    min-height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}
```

If you're trying to make sure all of your divs show up, you *could* try setting a [max-height](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_dim_max-height.asp) attribute in the div styles.

e.g.

```
.div-3{
    background-color:#3399FF;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, IE6 don't support min-height and max-height. (IE6 still has a lot of users.) But I think you can use the trick here to fix that. http://blog.whirix.com/2008/11/cross-browser-min-height-ie6-and-others.html